# Print data of a clicked row from tableView model

Tags: python, pyqt, tableview, pyqt5

there is the dialog:

```
class classsearchresult(QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.tableView.setShowGrid(False)
    self.tableView.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
    vh = self.tableView.verticalHeader()
    vh.setVisible(False)
    hh = self.tableView.horizontalHeader()
    hh.setVisible(False)
    hh.setStretchLastSection(True)
    self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.close)
    db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
    db.setDatabaseName('formuladatabase')
    db.open()
    self.projectModel = QtSql.QSqlQueryModel(self)
    self.projectModel.setQuery("select rowid, Name, Surname from search",db)
    self.tableView.setModel(self.projectModel)
    self.tableView.clicked.connect(self.handlebutton)
```

tableview works great just need to print that clicked row

```
def handlebutton(self):
    rows = self.tableView.selectionModel().selectedIndexes()
    print(self.projectModel.record(rows[0].row()).value("rowid").toInt())
    self.newwindow = classformularesult(self)
    self.newwindow.show()
```

been trying for a while but cant figure this one out.

Comment: What is the question? What happens when you run the code? What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: the code run fine except the print is[<PyQt5.QtCore.QModelIndex object at 0x03A6C9F0>] what i'm looking for is the data inside the selected row

Comment: So, `rows` is an object --- what methods can you call on it?

Comment: updated code made some improvement but still crashes

Answer (score 1):

Just a  note: I noticed you tagged PyQt5, but the docs aren't so good there, and I'm pretty confident all I'm stating here still applies (from PyQt4).

It appears as though you're assuming that `rows` is going to contain the data from your query, which it does not.  `selectedRows(),selectedColumns,selectedIndexes()` (documented here: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectedRows) all return type `list-of-QModelIndex`, which are basically indexes.. not data.

> list-of-QModelIndex QItemSelectionModel.selectedRows (self, int column
>   = 0)
>
> Returns the indexes in the given column for the rows where all columns
>   are selected.

I think it's easier to use selectedIndexes

> list-of-QModelIndex QItemSelectionModel.selectedIndexes (self)
>
> Returns a list of all selected model item indexes. The list contains
>   no duplicates, and is not sorted.

To get the data, model.record.value() returns a QVariant, to which you have to cast to the proper type for printing.  So, in your case:

```
rows = self.tableView.selectionModel().selectedIndexes()
print self.projectModel.record(rows[0].row()).value("rowid").toInt()
print self.projectModel.record(rows[0].row()).value("Name").toString()
print self.projectModel.record(rows[0].row()).value("Surname").toString()
```

The rows[0].row() is accessing element 0 of the "list-of-QModelIndex" type that's returned, and QModelIndex (http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmodelindex.html#details) has a row() method which returns the index of the row. Given the way you've set it up, the "list-of-QModelIndex" list should always be a single element list (you wired it up with the "clicked" signal), so the row[0] should return the proper element.

See here for additional information:
http://ftp.ics.uci.edu/pub/centos0/ics-custom-build/BUILD/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.7.2/doc/html/qtsql.html
About half way down there's a "Using the SQL Model Classes" heading with some good examples.

Comment: print (self.projectModel.record(rows[0].row()).value("rowid")) ITS WORKING thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

for the record and other in my situation the answers was

```
def handlebutton(self):
    rows = self.tableView.selectionModel().selectedIndexes()
    print(self.projectModel.record(rows[0].row()).value("rowid"))
    self.newwindow = classformularesult(self)
    self.newwindow.show()
```

thank you SEGFAULTCODER